# Get value from array based on index

Tags: arrays, amazon-athena

Quite new with Athena and have data structured as below:

| index | array |
| --- | --- |
| [1] | [1,2,3] |
| [2] | [2,3,4] |

And if I want to get the specific value from each array based on the value from the index column, how to get the below output?
e.g the expected output should be 1 and 3 based on the index provided

Comment: Is the index field is also an array with single value? or just an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Athena docs for accessing an array element: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/accessing-array-elements.html

- If `index` is an integer:

```
SELECT element_at(array, index)
FROM your_table
```

- If `index` is an array:

```
SELECT element_at(array, index[1])
FROM your_table
```